# Placing a clickable element inside a clickable container element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I'm trying to make the `#header` div clickable by wrapping a link element around it, but I cannot do it when it already has another image link inside the div. How would I fix this?

```css
#header {
border: 1px solid red;
background-color: red;
}
img {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href = 'index.php'>
<div id = 'header'>

<a href = 'profile.php?username=$username'>
<img src = 'https://www.iscattered.com/uploads/1590Chocolate_chip_cookies.jpg'>
</a> 

</div>
</a>
```

Now while the image link works just fine, the `#wrapper` div is not clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#header {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;    /* establish nearest positioned ancestor for abs. positioning */
    height: 50px;
}

#header a:first-child { 
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

#header a:last-child {
    position: absolute;      /* image now independently clickable */
    top: 0;                  /* position image anywhere you want inside #header */
    left: 0;
}

img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='header'>
    <a href='index.php'></a>
    <a href='profile.php?username=$username'>
    <img src='https://www.iscattered.com/uploads/1590Chocolate_chip_cookies.jpg'>
    </a>
</div>
```

NOTES:

- If you wrap a hyperlink inside another hyperlink, how is the browser supposed to know which link to execute?
- Instead, make the `#header` element entirely clickable, and absolutely position the image.
- Now the image can be clicked separately and positioned anywhere inside the `#header` element.

Comment: So, if we want to make the header clickable, everything that need to be inside the header need to be either absolute positioned, or fixed?

Comment: The header is entirely clickable. The absolutely positioned image hovers over the header and can be clicked separately.